# Animation of text getting written to be made in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

how do i make this code mobile compatible?
I want to use it in bootstrap.I tried running it by changing max width and max height,but that is not making any difference.The code is a short animation running on page load.

```css
body {
  background: #ffdd00;
  font-family: 'MisoRegular';
}
h1.main,
p.demos {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
.sp-container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px auto 0px auto;
}
.sp-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: open 0.4s linear forwards, squeeze 0.6s linear 5.5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: open 0.4s linear forwards, squeeze 0.6s linear 5.5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: open 0.4s linear forwards, squeeze 0.6s linear 5.5s forwards;
  animation: open 0.4s linear forwards, squeeze 0.6s linear 5.5s forwards;
}
.sp-content:after {
  content: '';
  width: 4px;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
.sp-container h2 {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.sp-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffdd00;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sp-wrap span {
  display: block;
  background: #ffdd00;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.sp-wrap span.sp-mid {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.sp-container .sp-right h2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.sp-wrap span.sp-mid {
  font-family: 'MisoBold';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 130px;
  position: relative;
}
.sp-left span.sp-top {
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 0.6s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4s backwards;
  -moz-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 0.6s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4s backwards;
  -ms-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 0.6s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4s backwards;
  animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 0.6s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4s backwards;
}
.sp-left span.sp-mid {
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
}
.sp-left span.sp-bottom {
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1.4s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.2s backwards;
  -moz-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1.4s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.2s backwards;
  -ms-animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1.4s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.2s backwards;
  animation: slideLeft 0.5s ease-in 1.4s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.2s backwards;
}
.sp-right span {
  text-align: left;
}
.sp-right span.sp-top {
  -webkit-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.4s backwards;
  -moz-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.4s backwards;
  -ms-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.4s backwards;
  animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.4s backwards;
}
.sp-right span.sp-mid {
  -webkit-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2.4s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2.4s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  -ms-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2.4s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
  animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 2.4s backwards, moveUp 0.6s linear 5s forwards;
}
.sp-right span.sp-bottom {
  -webkit-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 3.2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.6s backwards;
  -moz-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 3.2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.6s backwards;
  -ms-animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 3.2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.6s backwards;
  animation: slideRight 0.5s ease-in 3.2s backwards, fadeOut 1s linear 4.6s backwards;
}
.sp-wrap i {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffdd00;
  width: 60px;
}
.sp-wrap i:first-child {
  color: #000;
}
.sp-wrap i:last-child {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 6s backwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 6s backwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut 1s linear 6s backwards;
  animation: fadeOut 1s linear 6s backwards;
}
.sp-full {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 142px;
  width: 700px;
  left: 145px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 6.6s backwards;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 6.6s backwards;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 1s linear 6.6s backwards;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear 6.6s backwards;
}
.sp-full a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  -webkit-animation: zoomIn 0.7s ease-in-out 7s backwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomIn 0.7s ease-in-out 7s backwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomIn 0.7s ease-in-out 7s backwards;
  animation: zoomIn 0.7s ease-in-out 7s backwards;
}
.sp-full h2 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
.sp-full a:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes open {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes squeeze {
  0% {
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(120%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-120%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-170px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes open {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes squeeze {
  0% {
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(120%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-120%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-170px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
/**/

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes squeeze {
  0% {
    height: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(120%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-120%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-170px);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-container">
  <div class="sp-content">
    <div class="sp-wrap sp-left">
      <h2>
       <span class="sp-top">What if you wouldn't get</span> 
       <span class="sp-mid">spam</span> 
       <span class="sp-bottom">anymore?</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sp-wrap sp-right">
      <h2>
       <span class="sp-top">Wouldn't that be absolutely</span> 
       <span class="sp-mid">great<i>!</i><i>?</i></span> 
       <span class="sp-bottom">Yeah, it would!</span> 
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sp-full">
    <h2>A great way to get rid of spam!</h2>
    <a href="index3.html">Sign up now!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code and explain it briefly what you wanted to do

Comment: Did it,you might check it and help @GautamJha

Comment: @MananChawda: If my answer was helpful or correct, you're free to upvote it or mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I don't see, where you tried to use bootstrap, so I can't help you with that.

Your big problem trying to make it responsive, is that you have a lot of absolute positioned elements and use pixel values for `width` and positioning a lot.

The only quick option left is scaling it, so it always fits the viewport: https://jsfiddle.net/g600fu8a/2/

**changed HTML**

```
<div class="sp-container" id="scaleWrapper">
    ...
</div>
```

**additional CSS**

```
#scaleWrapper {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var initialWidth = 900; //just as default value
var scaleContent = function() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    //console.log("scaling ...", windowWidth, initialWidth);

    if(windowWidth < initialWidth) {
        var newScale = windowWidth / initialWidth;
        $('#scaleWrapper').css({
            '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
            '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
            '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
            '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
            'transform'         : 'scale(' + newScale + ')'
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    initialWidth = $('#scaleWrapper').width();
    scaleContent();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    scaleContent();
});
```

Explanation:
You defined `.sp-container` to have a fixed width of 900px. So I assume this is kind of a max-width, as it doesn't matter if the viewport get's any larger (since you applied a margin-auto as well).
Therefor we need to adjust this container if the viewport get's smaller than 900px. My approach is to scale it accordingly so that it always uses 100% of the viewports width (if smaller than 900px).
*(I made it more flexible by initially reading in the wrappers width and using that initial value for calculation.)*

Comment: Hello,I tried the suggestions that you gave.But its still not working.Although ,that javascript u used to scale might lead me to the answer i am looking for.Thanks for that.

Comment: @MananChawda this is working fine in Fiddle. make sure there are no error in console.

Comment: As @GautamJha wrote the code does work in my provided fiddle, so it seems you need more adaptation to your own code. You're free to ask for more guidance or help.

Comment: yep i tried it.its working fine in my project with little spacing issues,also in fiddle too.May be bootstrap that i have used might be creating those issues.Thanks for your valuable feedback! @GautamJha